# Can an Apple Watch have a Glance only?

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

Is it possible to only have a Glance (Glance Entry Point) in your Apple Watch app, skipping the actual Watch App (Main Entry Point)?

Answer (score 4):

Not at this time, unfortunately. Glances automatically launch the main app when tapped. You'll need an app for it to open.

Answer (score 0):

No. Perhaps Apple might add this feature in the future, but right now, you need an app.